# javascript modify script before execution

Tags: javascript, browser

I would like to modify a piece of javascript that gets loaded by a webpage before that code actually is executed.
I know where the line of code I want to modify is, and I can use the browser debugger to set a breakpoint just before that line, however, once the execution is paused I'm unable to modify the script code.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

PS: Please note that all the rest of the script can remain identical to the original, and I don't want to block all javascript execution, just change a single (or a few) line before my browser runs it.

Comment: Are you changing it permanently or temporarily?

Comment: @AvivLo temporarily I suppose? I don't have control over the server that is providing me the script, so I am only interested in local changes in the browser in the current "loading" of the page.

Comment: You will probably have to write another script that changes the script that you want to modify before you actually load it. This is just a theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tantamount to override, and there is already a question that answer that

[Override Javascript file in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580017/override-javascript-file-in-chrome)

Personally I would go with the local override option as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides)

Comment: Interesting, I hoped there would be an easier, and less browser-specific solution, but this is a good start. Thank you!