# Any way to intercept and modify external static javascript in an HTML? tamper monkey or grease monkey or any other way

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a page that loads javascript using a `<script src="some/script.js">` tag. I wanted to replace a string in the external javascript file. And I found no way to do this in chrome. local overrides could work, but I don't want to keep the devtools open to make this work.

I tried the following

```
window.onbeforescriptexecute = function(e)=>(modifier code)
```

or

```
window.addEventListener("beforescriptexecute", (e)=>{modifier code});
```

But they don't work at all. I also tried this snippet [here](https://github.com/jspenguin2017/Snippets/blob/master/onbeforescriptexecute.html), still with no luck.

**How can I make this work?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I edit javascript in my browser like I can use Firebug to edit CSS/HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657229/how-can-i-edit-javascript-in-my-browser-like-i-can-use-firebug-to-edit-css-html)

Comment: The code here seems overly truncated. What is the `modifier code` stub exactly? Which string do you want to replace in which external file? Please share a [mcve] of the modification you want to make and your full code attempt so far. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override Javascript file in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580017/override-javascript-file-in-chrome).  I found *Resource Override* works fine. If you want to use selenium, you can also refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251290/9758790) here.