# Insert log points in JavaScript using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to insert some log-points in a JavaScript that interprets some websocket data on a homepage. I can easily insert the logpoints by inserting them manually using the developer tools in Chrome. However, I would like automize this by doing it programmatically using python selenium. Is it possible to insert a logpoint in the JavaScript from python using selenium and ChromeDriver (or alternatively Firefox and Geckdriver)?

Here is a screenshot from the developer tools of what I would like to be able to do from python:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by log points? debugger breakpoints?

Comment: Yes, so break points that do not stop the code from executing, but primts a message in the console.

Comment: are you asking how to call console.log from python?

Comment: No,  the question if it is possible to insert a "console log break point" in the JavaScript from python.

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing. Maybe you should share a screenshot of what you're doing in dev tools

Comment: Hi @pguardiario, I have shared a screen shot of what I am trying to do. Another solution that would work for me would be to set up an override of the JavaScript such as it is done here [Override Javascript file in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580017/override-javascript-file-in-chrome) but also here I am stuck with figuring out how to do this from Python